# Select a structure(DDL) of the view without admin rights

Tags: database, oracle

I know there is a way to select a meta information from database about views, for example:

```
SELECT v.view_name, v.text 
FROM DBA_VIEWS v 
WHERE v.view_name LIKE 'VIEW_%'
```

but to access to the table DBA_VIEWS you need to login as admin. (I've tried SYS AS SYSDBA).

The question: is there a possibility to get this meta information about the views that you own?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you have access to the `USER_*` views that contain your objects. Your views will be in `USER_VIEWS`.

You also have access to the `ALL_*` views by default, this set of views contain the definition of the objects that you can access.